# problem with binarysearch(calculate the first,last,mid with the new values)

Tags: c#, windows, binary-search

The code below belongs to a binary search algorithm. The user enters numbers in textbox1 and enters the number that he want to find with binarysearch in textbox2.
now i have a problem with  it,i want when the value of mid,first,last changes it again begin the function.i mean that for example:when last=mid-1; the function begin again and calculate with the new value of last(i commented in codes for more explanation)
thanks

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strsearchnums = textBox2.Text;
        int result = binarysearch(strsearchnums);
        textBox14.Text = result.ToString();
    }
    public int binarysearch(string strsearchnum)
    {
        string[] source = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
        int[] nums = new int[source.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            nums[i] = Convert.ToInt32(source[i]);
        }


        int searchnum = Convert.ToInt32(strsearchnum);
        int first = nums.First();

        int last = nums.Last();

        while (1 <= nums.Length - 1)
        {
            int mid = (int)Math.Floor(nums.Length / 2.0) - 1;

            if (nums[0]> nums[nums.Length-1])
            {
                break;
           }

            if (searchnum < nums[mid])
            {
                last = mid - 1;

         binarysearch(strsearchnum);       ///i thought i should do like this but this isnt correct it becomes stackoverflow    
            }
            if (searchnum > nums[mid])
            {
                first = mid + 1;
      binarysearch(strsearchnum);      ///i thought i should do like this but this isnt correct it becomes stackoverflow    
            }
            if (searchnum == nums[mid])
            {


              return nums[mid];


            }

        }

        return -1; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i corrected the code like below and it corrected:

```
 public int binarysearch(int searchnum)
    {
        string[] source = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
        int[] nums = new int[source.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            nums[i] = Convert.ToInt32(source[i]);
        }
        int first = 0;
        int last = nums.Length - 1;


        while (1 <= nums.Length)
        {
            int mid = (int)Math.Floor((first + last) / 2.0);
            if (first > last)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (searchnum < nums[mid])
            {
                last = mid - 1;
            }
            if (searchnum > nums[mid])
            {
                first = mid + 1;
            }
            if (searchnum == nums[mid])
            {
                return nums[mid];
            }
        }
        return -1;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1st of all when user enter the numbers in the textbox then those numbers may not be sorted so you need to first sort the array because Binary Search algo works with the sorted sequences.

```
   1- Splitt the string with ',' and store in the int[] array.

  string[] strArray = textBox1.Text.split(new string[]{","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    List<int> lstInts = new List<int>();      
   foreach(string str in strArray)
   {
      int j;
      int k=0;

      if(int.TryParse(str,out j))
        {
           lstInts.Add(j);
        }
    }
     int[] bsArray = lstInts.ToArray();

   2- Now Sort the Array.
      Array.Sort(bsArray);

   3- Now use Array.Binaryearch() , if you wanna use  framework implementation which is optimized also

      Array.BinarySearch(bsArray, valueToBeSearched)

     if you don't wanna use Framework implementation than follow below algorithm

   public int DoBinarySearchNoNRecursively(int[] array, int value)
    {
        int high = array.Length - 1;

        int low = 0;

        while (low < high)
        {
            int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;

            if (value == array[mid])
                return mid;
            else if (value > array[mid])
                low = mid + 1;
            else if (value < array[mid])
                high = mid;

        }

        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First problem is that you're never changing the value of `strsearchnum` - so you will always get a Stackoverflow exception since its an infinite recursion. In general for a recursive binary search you want your binarySearch method to pass the number you are looking for, the min and the max and modify min and max according to the binary search algorithm. Method signature should be something like

```
int binarySearch(int min, int max, int num)
{

}
```

This should help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the BinarySearch work...

> The binary search algorithm is more
>   efficient than the linear search
>   algorithm, but it requires that the
>   array be sorted.

```
    // perform a binary search on the data      
     public int binarysearch(string strsearchnum)
{

    string[] source = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
    int[] data = new int[source.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        data[i] = Convert.ToInt32(source[i]);
    }


  int low = 0 ; // low end of the search area                
  int high = data.length - 1 ; // high end of the search area
  int middle = ( low + high + 1 ) / 2 ; // middle element    
  int location = -1; // return value; -1 if not found        

  do // loop to search for element
     {


    // if the element is found at the middle               
     if ( searchElement == data[ middle ] )                 
    location = middle; // location is the current middle

    // middle element is too high                      
    else if ( searchElement < data[ middle ] )         
    high = middle - 1 ; // eliminate the higher half
    else // middle element is too low                  
    low = middle + 1 ; // eliminate the lower half  

    middle = ( low + high + 1 ) / 2 ; // recalculate the middle
    } while ( ( low <= high ) && ( location == -1 ) );            

    return location; // return location of search key
   } // end method binarySearch
```